# Where can I find SQLite.Interop.dll files and bundle?

Tags: c#, sqlite, dll

I am working on a .Net application and planning to use SQLite as its back end.
I ended up with “Not able to load SQLite.Interop.DLL”
Then I found the documentation in http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

But I’m not able to find a zip that contains all the essential files mentioned in the above documentation. All the files are either separated or in NuGet packages.

Can someone help me out to find a zip the contains the following DLL files as a zip in a single zip ?

```
<bin>\System.Data.SQLite.dll
<bin>\System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll
<bin>\System.Data.SQLite.EF6.dll
<bin>\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll
<bin>\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll
```

I don’t want to reference a NuGet package with my project, as I’m building this application using ANT and signing this is a separate build server that I’ve setup to compile and check the MSI files and it’s generation.

I’ll add a copytask to my ant build and copy all the dll files to the project before building it into msi. The only thing missing is a zip that contains all these above essential files.

PS : I need this application to work on both x86 x64 arch.

Comment: "I don’t want to reference a NuGet package with my project" boy are you in the wrong line of work.

Comment: That is okay @Blindy this build server is not just for build this MSi but all MSI's we build. So I'm specifically looking for DLL zip.

Comment: nuget packages are zips ... anyway, create dummy project add dependencies, restore, check `packages` folder and copy desired files (or publish dummy project and get desired files from there)

Comment: @Selvin Thats sound good, can you share link to any of the nuget pachage that contains all these 5 DLLs ? I seem to have a hard time finding these dlls in a package. I'm so sorry, I'm downloading all the ZIPs, but unfortunately not able to fine Interop in any Nuget packages.

Answer (score 1):

I've Searched around almost many sites and like @Blindy and @Selvin said there is no way around NuGet packages it seems.

Hence, I've downloaded the NuGet package from http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.113.0/System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.113.0.nupkg here which seems to contain SQLite as well as Platform Interop files.

Once I've downloaded these,

- In VS, Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Source -> Added a new source as my local folder.
- I've placed the downloaded package inside this folder
- Project -> Right Click -> Manage NuGet packages -> Under the browser tab, I've selected the RHS filter as the source I've added in the previous step and the package I've downloaded was listed under here.
- I Installed them and this created a packages folder inside my solution directory.
- Then I was able to use System.Data.SQLite in my application. But it still threw "Could not load SQLite.Interop.dll". To tell the builder that you have to use the interop files, open the csproj file for the project and add,

```html
<ContentSQLiteInteropFiles>true</ContentSQLiteInteropFiles>
```

And then this started working properly. I might use this as a structure instead of running a copytask in ant I guess.

Thanks to @Selvin and @Blindy